# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function ibase_connect()

Tags: php, database, firebird, web-hosting

I have a firebird Server installed on a computer, which has a database
I can access my database while my php-based website is working under xampp server
but when I put my website in my real web hosting server (online)
I can't connect to my database (which is hosted by another server)
first time when I got undefined function ibase_connect() on my localhost machine I just enabled the extentsion in my xampp server
but when online there is no xampp server! how can I connect in this case? is there extensions as well in webhostinng just like xampp!?

Comment: Did you restart the server?

Comment: there is no server to be restarted

Comment: Contact your hoster for support. Looks like your config change broke the server and it can't start up. Maybe they don't have the necessary extension for Interbase/Firebird support.

Comment: apt install php-interbease

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thank you, I have contact the host provider and the haven't enabled the extension for Interbase/Firbird

Comment: @rstrelba it is a hosting service over internet so it is impossible to do linux commands over a hosting service xD